# Javascript window.getSelection() not giving me anything

Tags: javascript

So I'm going to look like a big idiot, but I can't get this to work. All it needs to do is pop up an alert telling you what text you selected. However, it doesn't look like `window.getSelection()` is going anything.

When I concatenate a regular string variable into the alert, it displays. But everything I've tried with `window.getSelection()` isn't giving me anything.

```js
function myFunction() {
 var selObj = window.getSelection();
 var selText = selObj.toString();
 alert("You selected " + selText + "!");
}
```

```html
Select some of the text : <input type="text" value="Hello world!" onselect="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Your code works fine for all modern browsers (IE 9 and above, chrome, safari and firefox) if you are trying to get a result on mobile device it may not work as expected in Android Chrome, check your code working test example here https://jsbin.com/bihiliw/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

You could try using onmouseup instead of onselect. When you use onselect, the event handler will be invoked the moment the user starts making a selection. And since initially nothing is selected, when your event handler runs, window.getSelection() will return an empty string. If you use onmouseup, the event handler will run after the user has made their selection, in which case, when you invoke window.getSelection(), it will correctly return the selection that the user has made.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    Select some of the text: <input type="text" value="Hello world!" onmouseup="myFunction()">

<script>
    function myFunction() {
       var selObj = window.getSelection();
       var selText = selObj.toString();
       alert("You selected " + selText + "!");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a really good idea; thanks! But it's still doing the same thing as before. I'm going to try restarting my browser and computer.

Comment: Still same results.

Comment: I'm able to see the selected text in the alert. Could you elaborate a bit more on what the problem is? Are you not able to see the text in the alert?